# How to know direction of signal in Schemetic Tracer of simvision?

Tags: vhdl, cadence

I am trying to tracing the signal at Schemetic Tracer in simvision(cadence).

But It's really hard to find for some signal which have direction.
Is there anyway to know the direction of port in Schemetic Tracer?

Answer (score 0):

Yellow arrow on left of port name, pointing into box, input. Arrow on right of port name, output.